# PHP: Case-insensitive parameters

Tags: php, variables, performance, query-string, case-insensitive

How do I accept passed `GET` or `POST` values case insensitively?

Like `sample.php?OrderBy=asc` will still be the same as `sample.php?orderby=asc` or `sample.php?ORDERBY=asc`

Is there a means of achieving the above efficiently?

Comment: Not sure of a good solution, but I ran into a problem like that where the hashed password has gotten lower-cased and was unable to use it; so be careful, and I would suggest looking to see why this happens in the first place; usually when converting from HTTP to HTTPS (or back), the URL gets lower-cased.

Comment: What is the reason to change case?

Comment: well im working on an API where the system previously serves other API clients that use uppercase and recently we made API some changes including the decision to honor lower-cased parameters. so in order to maintain backward compatibility with the previous API users, i am faced with this kind of problem.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You could use [`array_change_key_case()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php) to create a copy of `$_GET` with either all uppercase or all lowercase keys.

```
$_GET_lower = array_change_key_case($_GET, CASE_LOWER);
$orderby = isset($_GET_lower['orderby']) ? $_GET_lower['orderby'] : 'asc';
echo $orderby;
```

(I say "create a copy" simply because I don't like polluting the original superglobals, but it's your choice to overwrite them if you wish.)

For that matter, it'd still be better if you just stick to case-sensitive matching since it might be easier on both search engine and human eyes, as well as easier on your code... **EDIT:** OK, based on your comment I can see why you'd want to do something like this.

Comment: What is the reason to change case?

Comment: When launching the default web browser with a Shell command from VBA, I've had the url mysteriously changed to all lower case if the browser is the Windows 10 Edge browser.  But not on all Windows 10 computers, only some.

Comment: I have been working on an API that needed to recognize that `ID`, `Id` and `id` are the same... Thanks @BoltClock