# PHP Login Database Issues

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP so please be patient with me! I am trying to set up a user login page but every time I click log in it won't recognize the data that is already in the database. I currently have 7 sections in a the table but only taking data from 2 sections. I am unsure where abouts I am going wrong could be the php or the MySQL queries  Would someone help me please!

```
 <?PHP

$email = "";
$pword = "";
$errorMessage = "";
$num_rows = 0;

function quote_smart($value, $handle) {

   if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
       $value = stripslashes($value);
   }

   if (!is_numeric($value)) {
       $value = "'" . mysql_real_escape_string($value, $handle) . "'";
   }
   return $value;
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $pword = $_POST['Password'];

    $email = htmlspecialchars($email);
    $pword = htmlspecialchars($pword);

    $e_mail = "root";
    $pass_word = "";
    $database = "the_travel_cult";
    $server = "127.0.0.1";

    $db_handle = mysql_connect($server, $e_mail, $pass_word);
    $db_found = mysql_select_db($database, $db_handle);

    if ($db_found) {

        $email = quote_smart($email, $db_handle);
        $pword = quote_smart($pword, $db_handle);


        $SQL = "SELECT * FROM user_login WHERE Email='$email' AND Password='$pword'";
        $result = mysql_query($SQL);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
        //if(!$result) die ('Unable to run query:'.mysql_error());

        if ($result) {
            if ($num_rows > 0) {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = "1";
                header ("Location: SignedIn.php");
            }
            else {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = "";
                //$errorMessage = "Not Registered";
                header ("Location: Register.php");              
            }   
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
        }

    mysql_close($db_handle);

    }

    else {
        $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
    }
}


?>

<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="HomePage.php">

<form method=post action=”login.php”>

<p><center><strong>Email Addres:</strong></center><br>
<center><input type=”text” name= 'email' value="<?PHP print $email;?>" size=40 maxlength=100></center>
<p><center><strong>Password</strong></center><br>
<center><input type=”text” name= 'password' value="<?PHP print $pword;?>" size=40 maxlength=20></center>

<P align = center>
<INPUT TYPE = "Submit" Name = "Submit1"  VALUE = "Login">
<form action="Register.php"> <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"> </form>
```

Comment: I noticed both `$email` and `$e_mail` in your code above, anything special between them?

Comment: what exactly is the php error

Comment: Plus you have strange quotes in `”login.php”` which I don't know if this will cause havoc.

Comment: Is it connecting to database ? check by `mysql_connect($server, $e_mail, $pass_word) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Never even seen those quotes `”login.php”`... Also, you're missing your quotes on `form method=post`. This looks like a whole buncha copy-pasta thrown into one file. @Fred it looks to me like `$email` refers to the users email address, whereas `$e_mail` is the username of the database user. EDIT: CONFIRMED, those quotes don't work... IMHO, I'd start over from scratch. You are using so much deprecated functionality you'll end up having to rewrite anyway.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it in quotes twice? You have `'$email'` which has quotes, then you add quotes again in `quote_smart()`? So you end up with `Email=''email@email.com''`

Comment: he also has `2` POSTS happening and `3` `<form...` ouch.

Comment: your `input` element has also special double quotes `type=”text” `

Comment: You also never close the first two forms on the page... `<FORM NAME ="form1" METHOD ="POST" ACTION ="HomePage.php">` and `<form method=post action=”login.php”>`

Comment: I should post an answer with one word: "REWRITE"

Comment: [The Pasta](http://www.docstoc.com/docs/24675608/Sample-PHP-to-prevent-SQL-injection-function-quote_smart(value)

Answer (score 2):

First off, congratulations on starting to code. I hope you're having fun!

It looks like you might have a case of "case sensitivity" going on. I noticed that you have the following code at the top:

```
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$pword = $_POST['Password'];
```

However, in your HTML, you're actually passing those variables named in all lowercase. Try changing either the code at the top to:

```
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pword = $_POST['password'];
```

Or the name of your inputs to "Email" and "Password" (again, notice the uppercase first letter). An easy way to check if the problem is here (vs something in the query) is to

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

to see what exactly your script is getting from the form submission.

For more information, see PHP's http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php or check out a related post to see how you can make your own case insensitivity check though be warned: it's more work. [PHP: Case-insensitive parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211420/php-case-insensitive-parameters)