# How do I get a case-insensitive parameter from a URL in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Suppose I have the following URL:

```
  https://www.example.com
```

I add a name parameter with a value "John" to the url as follow:

```
  https://www.example.com?name=John
```

In order to get the name parameter's value from the URL, I have try

```
   $_GET["name"]
```

However, people might not pay attention to the case and type the parameter in upper case or uppercase and lower-case commbine. How do I get the parameter's value case-insenstively?

for example, **`$_GET["name"], $_GET["Name"], and $_GET["nAme"]`** will return the same value.

Comment: [make it lowercase](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) after getting the value: `$name = strtolower($_GET['name'])`, then you can do all of your comparisons to lowercase values like `$name === "john"`, which will catch any lower/uppercase characters like `John`, `JOHN`, `jOhN`, etc.

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones Just editing my question. $_GET["name"] doesn't return the value if the parameter in the URL is upper case

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4211420/php-case-insensitive-parameters

Comment: @j08691 any other ways you can think of?

Comment: @Rongeegee Is there a problem with the solution in the link I posted?

Comment: @j08691 no. Just wondering if there is a one line solution

Comment: _"However, people might not pay attention to the case and type the parameter in upper case or uppercase and lower-case commbine"_ - what "people"? _Users_ should not have to type in such URLs manually in the first place; and _developers_ need to be able to read the documentation you provide for such features. You are trying to fix a non-issue here IMHO.